# Struggling with how to combine groups of rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame like so

```
product_id view_count purchase_count
1           11         1   
2           20         3
3           5          2
...
```

I would like to transform this into a table that groups by view_count and sums the purchase_count for an interval for instance.

```
view_count_range total_purchase_count
0-10                 45
10-20                65
```

These view_count_ranges will be of fixed size. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to group ranges like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cut` is a handy tool for this sort of thing.  here's one way:

```
#First make some data to work with 
#I suggest you do this in the future as it makes it 
#easier to provide you with assistance.
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(product_id=1:15, view_count=sample(1:20, 15, replace=T), 
    purchase_count=sample(1:8, 15, replace=T))
dat   #look at the data

#now we can use cut and aggregate by this new variable we just created
dat$view_count_range <- with(dat, cut(view_count, c(0, 10, 20)))
aggregate(purchase_count~view_count_range, dat, sum)
```

**Which yields:**

```
  view_count_range purchase_count
1           (0,10]             39
2          (10,20]             31
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Tyler's answer and starting with his example `dat`, you might find it easier and quicker to write queries like this in [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) :

```
> require(data.table)
> DT = as.data.table(dat)

> DT[, sum(purchase_count), by=cut(view_count,c(0,10,20))]
         cut V1
[1,] (10,20] 31
[2,]  (0,10] 39
```

That's it. Just one line. Easy to write, easy to read.

Notice it put the (10,20] group first. That's because by default it retains the order that each group first appears in the data (the first `view_count` is 11 in this data set).  To sort the groups instead, change `by` to `keyby` :

```
> DT[, sum(purchase_count), keyby=cut(view_count,c(0,10,20))]
         cut V1
[1,]  (0,10] 39
[2,] (10,20] 31
```

And to name the result columns :

```
> DT[,list( purchase_count = sum(purchase_count) ),
     keyby=list( view_count_range = cut(view_count,c(0,10,20) ))]
     view_count_range purchase_count
[1,]           (0,10]             39
[2,]          (10,20]             31
```